# grails generate war error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: debugging, grails, war

I've tried to generate war file in grails with command :

```
grails war
```

but this error is shows up, and this is the first time with this error, previously war is generated normally.

i know that array out of bound will be show up if the index doesn't exist in the arraylist, but i don't know which array? because all process in my application working fine.

can anyone help me please? :(

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.loadArguments(InvocationWriter.java:192)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeDirectMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:342)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:648)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(StatementWriter.java:604)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:354)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitExpressionStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:509)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:155)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:455)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitStdMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:319)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitConstructorOrMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:276)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:396)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1059)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClass(AsmClassGenerator.java:180)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$14.call(CompilationUnit.java:786)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1027)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:542)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:519)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$compile.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageCompiler$_compileGSP_closure1.doCall(GroovyPageCompiler.groovy:144)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor203.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods.withStream(IOGroovyMethods.java:1160)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.withInputStream(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1523)
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when you use grails run-app? If not perhaps try grails clean.

Comment: the array concerned here is of arguments for war command like you can put grails war xyz.war will generate a war named xyz.

Comment: I have tried 2 way above, but still not working... hmm... :(

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error.

1. I uninstalled the version of grails i was using ( i use sdkman ) and
2. manually deleted my .grails folder.
3. Re-install grails version,
4. ran cleanAll

and the grails war worked for me again.